# Why does stack blitz not accepting function on click event?

Tags: stackblitz

i am trying to exicute a click event on button, button getting error that function is not defined.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
function myFunction() {
console.log('fun should work');
}
```

i tried above approach but did not get solution.